# Default location of Dropbox installation files in Debian 8.1?

Tags: linux, debian, dropbox

I installed Dropbox by the package manager *apt-get*. 
In Ubuntu, they locate at the following according to this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/633824/when-starting-dropbox-ioerror-errno-13-permission-denied)

```
/var/lib/dropbox/.dropbox-dist/dropbox-lnx.x86_64-3.6.6/futures-2.1.3-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/top_level.txt
```

but `find /var/lib -iname "*dropbox*` gives me in Debian 8.1

```
 /var/lib/dpkg/info/dropbox.md5sums 
 /var/lib/dpkg/info/dropbox.postrm 
 /var/lib/dpkg/info/dropbox.postinst    
 /var/lib/dpkg/info/dropbox.list
 /var/lib/apt/lists/linux.dropbox.com_debian_dists_jessie_Release.gpg 
 /var/lib/apt/lists/linux.dropbox.com_debian_dists_jessie_main_binary-i386_Packag‌​es 
 /var/lib/apt/lists/linux.dropbox.com_debian_dists_jessie_Release 
 /var/lib/apt/lists/linux.dropbox.com_debian_dists_jessie_main_binary-amd64_Packa‌​ges.
```

but not sure which permissions I should change for extra read as for dropbox files.

Where are the default files of Dropbox in Debian 8.1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find your installed packages of Dropbox:

```
dpkg --list | grep dropbox
```

For each package list the location of installed files, i.e.:

```
dpkg -L dropbox
```

Answer (score 0):

The default Location should be ~/Dropbox if you did not change the folder location by default.

Comment: Sorry not being clear. I mean installation files of Dropbox.